# GRE 6-choose-2 question: How can "orientation" be synonymous with "bias"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, synonyms, exam-questions

This question is asking you to choose two synonyms from a list to fill in the blank: ([source](http://www.gter.net/bbs/index/view.html?mobile=yes&tid=1870707))

> Despite the general ______ of Roman archaeological studies toward the major cities and their monuments, archaeology has contributed much to a better understanding of rural developments in Roman territory.
>
> A. openness
>   B. indifference
>   C. hostility
>   D. animus
>   E. bias
>   F. orientation

An unofficial answer is E/F, but after referring to the dictionary, I can't see why "orientation" is a synonym of "bias".

Meanwhile, I think C/D is also reasonable （contrary to their good understanding of rural developments）.

Comment: E and F are acceptable, but this does not mean that _bias_ and _orientation_ are synonymous. It means that both are sensible nouns in this context. C and D are poor choices. If the bias in Roman archaeology were presented as being toward _rural_ centers, C and D would be possible, but the sentence clearly implies that the opposite is the case. Study the meaning of _despite_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, this is good enough to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the GRE, sometimes the choice of answer may not have an exact synonym. We have to look for the proper choice which is required by a question.
Here *bias* and *orientation* are the correct answers. *Bias* means a decision which favors one party, and *orientation* means an inclination towards something or somebody.

Here Roman archaeological studies give priority to city development over rural developments, and that is why *bias* makes sense. Roman archaeological studies are inclined towards city development rather than rural development, which makes sense and makes *orientation* an appropriate answer.

Comment: Then would you mind to edit and make a correction?

Comment: Actually, I exaggerated: There are some determiners in your answer, but there are several other errors. It is good that you answered the question, though and we welcome your efforts! I will make some changes that may help you understand your mistakes. We hope you will keep learning and trying to help others.

Comment: +1 The grammar of your answer has some issues, but your basic idea and explanation are strong, and I am glad you submitted it.  Welcome to ell.

Comment: My native language is Nepali.I have a lot of issues with English grammar, I am working on it.I guess if I am afraid of making a mistake I wouldn't learn and improve. Thank you, P.E. Dant and  Adam, for your comment.I really appreciate your comment.Could you please suggest some good books for learning English grammar.